# Wrap XmlNode with tags

Tags: c#, .net, xmlnode

I have XmlNode with some xml tags. And need to wrap this node into two parent tags "" and "". So what I do:

```
XmlNode newObjectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"newobject", null);
XmlNode objectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "objects", null);

newObjectNode.AppendChild(myNode);
objectNode.AppendChild(newObjectNode);
```

So I want to have something like:

```
<objects>
  <newobject>
    my node here
  </newobject>
</objects>
```

But I have

```
<newobject>
  <newobject>
    my node here
  </newobject>
</newobject>
```

What wrong?

Comment: It's a XmlNode that contains some InnerXml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe

```
XmlNode objectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "newobject", null);
```

->

```
XmlNode objectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "objects", null);
```

Comment: Sorry thats my fault, I mean that the second line is "objects"

Answer (score 0):

the string you are use is `newobject` for both of the `nodes`, try this

```
XmlNode newObjectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"newobject", null);
XmlNode objectNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "objects", null);
```

Comment: Sorry thats my fault, I mean that the second line is "objects"

Comment: @Gleb thats the reason your question is downgraded.Try to resolve the issue from your own first from every aspect, before posting it on SO. SO experts should definitely help you out, but what you have learned from your brainstorming to the issue will help you out in future.

Comment: That was a mistake in my post, not in the code. Look to the code again, now it as in my program.